# POST request trying to make a Session authentication in the REST SERVER return a HTML error 406 Not acceptable

Tags: users, 8

I have a REST server in drupal working. I get data if I go to the server endpoint.

In Navigator:

```
http://localhost/drupal-7.19/restserver/user/
```

Work fine.

I have created a PHP to make the Session authentication:

```
<?php
// REST Server URL

/*
* Server REST - user.login
*/

// REST Server URL
$request_url = "http://localhost/drupal-7.19/restserver/user/login";

// User data
$user_data = array(
  "username" => "test",
  "password" => "test",
);
$user_data = http_build_query($user_data);

// cURL
$curl = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json")); // Accept JSON response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Do a regular HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_data); // Set POST data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);  // Ask to not return Header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Check if login was successful
if ($http_code == 200) {
  // Convert json response as array
  $logged_user = json_decode($response);
}
else {
  // Get error msg
  $http_message = curl_error($curl);
  die($http_message);
}
echo "END php \n";

?>
```

But I getting this error:

```
TestAuth.php The requested URL returned error: 406
```

Comment: What are the values you have in the request formatters and parsers for your resource ?

Comment: user (allow to login, logout, and register) and node

Comment: I mean the SERVER tab where you choose types and encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you choose the appropriate Data types for `request formatters` and `parsers` for your resource. You will find it under `admin/structure/services/list/your_resource_name/server`. Having said that, this works for me :

```
// .xml asks for xml data in response, choose what you need here
$service_url = 'http://localhost/your-endpoint/user/login.xml'; 
$post_data = array(
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'pass',
);
// We format post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded so make 
// sure that you tick it under the rest server parser options.
$post_data = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&'); 
// Initialize the request
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
// We want curl to return a string
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
// Choose method POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Feed the data to POST to curl
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
// Make it verbose for debugging.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// Go!
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print "LOGIN RESPONSE:\n";
var_dump($response);
// parse the response we get (in XML see above)...
```

Comment: You mean 
Home » Administration » Structure » Services » Edit Server ; Request parsing? There are all selected less " application/x-www-form-urlencoded " ; formatts accept all less jsons

Comment: If you use my sample code, you should select `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, otherwise it will not work. For the formats select the ones you are using, or just select them all (just for testing, then go back and select only the ones you need, JSON in your case).

Comment: That works. I didn't think that the URL was encoded using json protocol.

Comment: It is not. What it is encoded in JSON (format) is the response that you get. The data that you POST is encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Suerte!